# Local port forwarding automatically configured on boot?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding

I have software which needs to run as a non-root user, but needs to listen on port 80 and 443.

With iptables, this isn't all that difficult:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Though this is simple, how should I persist it to take effect on boot? I tried `iptables-save`, but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: Depends on OS/distro. They all have their own way of initializing iptables. `iptables-save` just dumps the rules.

Comment: My bad, it's Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method for restoring `iptables` rules on boot for Debian-based systems is using a pre-up rule in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

First you need to save the current rules to a file:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

In the block for the relevant interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` add:

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

Other methods, such as loading via network-manager can be found on the [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration_on_startup).